# How to dismiss a SwiftUI ColorPicker Popover programmatically

Tags: swift, swiftui

Unlike developer-created Popovers that have @Bindings to display/dismiss them, ColorPicker Popover is created by iPadOS itself. Take a look:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var myColor = Color.red

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ColorPicker("Label text", selection: $myColor)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

And it is a usual Popover:

[image: Screenshot]

How can I dismiss it programmatically?

PS If you are wondering why I need that. I need to display an Alert at some point, and this Popover might be opened by the user. As Alerts and Popovers can't be shown simultaneously — I must close the Popover first.

Comment: have you tried `dismiss` from `@Environment`?

Comment: @loremipsum if you mean the `@Environment(\.dismiss) private var dismiss` and then call `dismiss()`. I think that code should be inside the Popover view? But I don't have access to that code as it's internal to SwiftUI. Or you meant something else?

Comment: You can pass `dismiss` as a function to be called as needed.

Comment: I think `dismiss()` action applies to the environment where we declared it. And I can't put `@Environment` code inside SwiftUI's ColorPicker Popover — it's created by iPadOS.

Comment: you have a `@State` variable attached to `isPresented` to show a popover, why not just switch it to false when you are want to present an alert? (from parent view that is)

Comment: @klangfarb I don't have an `@State` var attached to `isPresented`. Or is there a default `isPresented` variable? Can you expand your comment, please?

Comment: I guess it all depends on where the error is being thrown and where you catch it. I get the impression you are trying to affect the UI from somewhere other than the presentation layer

Comment: @loremipsum I think you answered the wrong comment thread. What error are you talking about? I don't catch any errors. I just want to close the Popover programmatically. But thank you for trying to help :)

Comment: No I assumed alert == error, you can use `dismiss` from a `View` but I assume that you are presenting an alert from somewhere other than a `View`.

Comment: I just have a Main View. We can call it Parent View. It can present the standard ColorPicker and Alerts. But not both at once. So when I need to show an Alert - I must make sure to dismiss the ColorPicker first if it's showing. And I need to dismiss it from that Main View.

Comment: It would be helpful to see a reproducible scneario that is currently not working, i.e. how are you are presenting `ContentView`, and what is the problem with Alert. In your posted code, there isn't any overlays, and not clear what is it that you want to dismiss.

Comment: @klangfarb Sure. The non-working code is https://pastecode.io/s/6yue2msc Run it on the iPad, tap on the round button of ColorPicker, then, without dismissing the ColorPicker, tap on "Show Alert". You won't see any Alerts, because you must close the previous Popover first. And that is my question.